# Getting exported part instance from MEF container

Tags: mef

How I can the existing instance of an exported part in MEF container . If I have class A which was composed in the container , I need in some places in my code to get the instance , if I call GetExortedValue() , then if class A signed with CreationPolicy.NonShared , then it'll be instantiated again and I need the current one .

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously calling `GetExportedValue<T>` on your container could result on the generation of a new instance of `T` (depending on the `CreationPolicy` used for the part), but there is an option to call `GetExport<T>` which will return you a `Lazy<T>` instance. This is the singular part that is generated and only generated the once:

```
var part = container.GetExport<IMyInterface>();
```

In the above example, `part` would be an instance of `Lazy<IMyInterface>`, so when you first access `part.Value`, the delegate bound in the `Lazy<IMyInterface>` calls back to the container to create and compose the `IMyInterface` instance and is returned. Subsequent calls to `part.Value` will always return this same instance.